# Прогрессивное улучшение на примере отображения формы с JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма, которая появляется при клике на соответствующую кнопку (отлавливаю клик).
Задача - сделать так, чтобы при отключенном JS форма отображалась на странице.

Таким образом изначально в HTML я вешаю класс, который отображает форму, а при работающем JS она должна скрываться автоматически и открываться по клику.

Вопрос - какое событие нужно отлавливать, чтобы изначально скрыть форму?   `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: можно просто скрипт поместить после определения формы

Comment: Существует тег `<noscript>`, который показывает содержимое, если в браузере отключен js. Можно продублировать в него компонент формы, если вы на фреймворке работаете типа реакта. Или сделать так: форма изначально показана, а js ее скрывает. Соответственно, если js нет, то и форма не скроется.

Answer (score 2):

Так же для отображения чего-либо при отключенном скрипте используется HTML5 тег `noscript`

P.S. пример без использования данного тега

```js
var text = document.querySelector('p');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
text.style.display = 'none';

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (text.style.display === 'none') {
    text.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    text.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<button>Show text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет тег `noscript` - поместите в него форму.